# How do you delete duplicate values assigned to a specific name in VBA/Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

For example I have the Table below

| Name | Product |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | Ice Cream |
| Tom | Ice Cream |
| Tom | Toys |
| Jack | Ice Cream |

I'm trying to remove duplicate products associated with a certain name, so I would need to remove the extra Tom and Ice Cream row, but ensure that the Jack and Ice Cream row is kept.

I also have the following code I used in VBA to try to loop the filter in order to remove the duplicates, but it doesn't seem to work as I can't only select the sorted range when using Remove Duplicates

```
Sub Delete_Duplicates()

Dim Cell As Range

Worksheetname.Range("A1:B1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
For Each Cell In Worksheetname("E1").End(xlDown)
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$8570").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Cell
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Any other methods using VBA or just Excel are much welcomed

Comment: You don't need to loop, I think you just need `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1", Range("B2").End(xlDown))RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header _
        :=xlYes`

Comment: Mate how do I upvote you? @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns

Comment: Also avoid using `xldown`. Find the [Last Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) and then use `ws.Range("A1:B" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix your code like this:

```
Sub Delete_Duplicates()
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

As suggested by @SiddharthRout, the right way would be:

```
Sub Delete_Duplicates()
Dim LR As Long
'we get position of last non empty cell in column B
LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'remove duplicates
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$" & LR).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

**Try using second one**, it's indeed better, because `Range("B2").End(xlDown))` does not always return the last non empty cell in column B.